# Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.UtilsArgumentException Invalid Kusto connection scheme: '' when using API 'Query'

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.UtilsArgumentException   **Invalid Kusto connection scheme: ''** when using API 'Query'

Trying to use AAD Federated **application authentication** based-on a given ApplicationClientId and ApplicationKey in a netcoreapp2.2.

Referencing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/connection-strings/kusto for sample code.

```
var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(dataExplorerUrl, DatabaseName)
    .WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(
        AppClientId,
        AppClientSecret,
        TenantId);

using (var client = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider(kustoConnectionStringBuilder))
{
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.  Had a **$** in front of {}, too much javascript.
Would help if the error was more informative.  Wound up chasing the **ConnectionScheme** property issue, when it was an incorrect cluster url.

```
var dataExplorerUrl = $"https://${ClusterName}.westus2.kusto.windows.net";

should be

var dataExplorerUrl = $"https://{ClusterName}.westus2.kusto.windows.net";
```